# Flask/PyMongo - Initialize pymongo at the top of the app

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, pymongo

I'm trying to scale up my first Flask app and am not understanding the structure needed to use a pymongo db in multiple modules. For example, here is my new structure:

```
run.py
app/
├── __init__.py
├── forms.py
├── static/
├── templates/
└── views/
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── bookmarklet.py
    ├── main.py
    └── user.py
```

Prior to trying to scale this, I had this at the top of my single `views.py` file:

```
from flask.ext.pymongo import PyMongo
mongo = PyMongo(app)
with app.app_context():
    mongo.db.user.ensure_index("email", unique=True)
```

The goal is to be able to use this `mongo` instance in all of the view modules as well as the `forms.py` module. I've tried these two things:

1. Put the above snippet in the `app/__init__.py` file, but can't seem to make it accessible to any other modules. I tried doing this: `app.db = mongo.db` (but it wasn't available downstream)
2. Put the above snippet into each module that needs it, but then I get the error that there are multiple mongo instances with the same prefix.

Where should this initialization go in order to make it accessible everywhere in the app?

**EDIT**

It sounds like I'm doing it right but there is something else going on. I'm posting my more complete code and error.

app/__init__.py

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
from app.views import main

app.config.update(
    DEBUG = True,
    SECRET_KEY = "not telling",
    WTF_CSRF_ENABLED = False,
)

app.jinja_env.add_extension('pyjade.ext.jinja.PyJadeExtension')

from flask.ext.pymongo import PyMongo
mongo = PyMongo(app)
with app.app_context():
    mongo.db.user.ensure_index("email", unique=True)
```

app/views/main.py

```
from app import app
from flask import render_template, redirect, request, flash, url_for
from flask.ext.jsonpify import jsonify
from app.forms import *

from app import *
print mongo
```

Error:

```
(venv)imac: me$ ./run.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./run.py", line 4, in <module>
    from app import app
  File "/Users/me/Dropbox/development/test/app/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from app.views import main
  File "/Users/me/Dropbox/development/test/app/views/main.py", line 9, in <module>
    print mongo
NameError: name 'mongo' is not defined
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SOLVED**

The mistake in my `__init__.py` file was that I was importing my views to early. You have to do that at the end!

**WRONG**

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
from app.views import main # <- TOO EARLY

app.config.update(
    DEBUG = True,
    SECRET_KEY = "not telling",
    WTF_CSRF_ENABLED = False,
)

app.jinja_env.add_extension('pyjade.ext.jinja.PyJadeExtension')

from flask.ext.pymongo import PyMongo
mongo = PyMongo(app)
with app.app_context():
    mongo.db.user.ensure_index("email", unique=True)
```

**RIGHT**

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.pymongo import PyMongo

app = Flask(__name__)

mongo = PyMongo(app)
with app.app_context():
    mongo.db.user.ensure_index("email", unique=True)

app.config.update(
    DEBUG = True,
    SECRET_KEY = "not telling",
    WTF_CSRF_ENABLED = False,
)

app.jinja_env.add_extension('pyjade.ext.jinja.PyJadeExtension')

# AT THE BOTTOM!
from app.views import main
```

Answer (score 2):

Put that snippet in `app/__init__.py`. If you want to access it in `forms.py`, for instance, try:

```
...
from app import *
# then you can use mongo here
print mongo
...
```

If you want to access it in `user.py`, for instance, try the same code above.

Check if this works for you. If not, show me the error message and I will think about solution two.

Comment: I appreciate you taking a second look. I've posted code and error above.

Comment: I have this feeling that it is something to do with the usage of `app`. At the beginning of the file I have to do `from app import app`. Then later, if I reference `app`, how does it know which to use? I've also tried it without `from app import *` and just used `print app.mongo` to no avail.